# Ansible print specific fields from vmware_host_vmhba_facts

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-facts

I'm using vmware_host_vmhba_facts module, my goal is to extract for any esx, the status of hbas.

I attach a short output:

```
PLAY [Check HBA status] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Gather facts about vmhbas of all ESXi Host in the given Cluster] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost -> localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "cluster_host_vmhbas": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "hosts_vmhbas_facts": {
            "ita-esx01.net": {
                "vmhba_details": [
                    {
                        "adapter": "Intel Corporation Lewisburg SATA AHCI Controller",
                        "bus": 0,
                        "device": "vmhba38",
                        "driver": "ahci",
                        "location": "0000:00:11.5",
                        "model": "Lewisburg SATA AHCI Controller",
                        "status": "unknown",
                        "type": "BlockHba"
                    },
                    {
                        "adapter": "QLogic Corp 2600 Series 16Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA",
                        "bus": 95,
                        "device": "vmhba3",
                        "driver": "qlnativefc",
                        "location": "0000:5f:00.0",
                        "model": "2600 Series 16Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA",
                        "node_wwn": "23:06:11:22:94:35:05:46:63",
                        "port_type": "unknown",
                        "port_wwn": "23:06:39:37:69:32:72:57:29",
                        "speed": 16,
                        "status": "online",
                        "type": "Fibre Channel"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ita-esx02.net": {
                "vmhba_details": [
                    {
                        "adapter": "Intel Corporation Lewisburg SATA AHCI Controller",
                        "bus": 0,
                        "device": "vmhba38",
                        "driver": "ahci",
                        "location": "0000:00:11.5",
                        "model": "Lewisburg SATA AHCI Controller",
                        "status": "unknown",
                        "type": "BlockHba"
                    },
                    {
                        "adapter": "QLogic Corp 2600 Series 16Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA",
                        "bus": 95,
                        "device": "vmhba4",
                        "driver": "qlnativefc",
                        "location": "0000:5f:00.1",
                        "model": "2600 Series 16Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA",
                        "node_wwn": "23:06:11:22:94:35:05:46:64",
                        "port_type": "unknown",
                        "port_wwn": "23:06:39:37:69:32:72:57:30",
                        "speed": 16,
                        "status": "online",
                        "type": "Fibre Channel"
                    },
```

Following this output, I'd like to have a similar output:

```
ita-esx01.net:
vmhba38 status unknown
vmhba3  status online

ita-esx02.net:
vmhba38 status unknown
vmhba4 status online
```

Do you have any hint? 
Thank you

Comment: I think you're going to have to parse the debug JSON yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, select the data first

```
- set_fact:
    net_status: "{{ net_status|
                    default({})|
                    combine({item.key: item.value.vmhba_details|
                                       json_query('[].{key: device,
                                                       value: status}')})
                    }}"
  loop: "{{ cluster_host_vmhbas.hosts_vmhbas_facts|dict2items }}"
```

and then print it

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
  vars:
    msg: |
      {{ item.key }}:
      {% for dev in item.value %}
      {{ dev.key }} status {{ dev.value }}
      {% endfor %}
  loop: "{{ net_status|dict2items }}"
```

The abridged output is

```
"msg": [
    "ita-esx02.net:", 
    "vmhba38 status unknown", 
    "vmhba4 status online", 
    ""
]

"msg": [
    "ita-esx01.net:", 
    "vmhba38 status unknown", 
    "vmhba3 status online", 
    ""
]
```

Comment: impressive, I don't have words. Do you have any website or other where I can learn this? I don't like to bother asking things :)

Comment: FWIW. I keep the Ansible examples in [GitHub](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples). Thank you for comments.